# NullReferenceException in Windows Phone 7 while navigating

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, pivot

hi i am a new guy to windows phone7 and SO too. Here i have pivot control as root and i am trying to navigate to another page using the service uri.

Following is the piece of code which i am using to navigate from pivot to another view

And then i created the another page called page1.xaml

In the mainpage.cs i write the code like:

```
PivotItem p = new PivotItem();
            p.Header = "Home";
            p.Content = new page1(); 
            main.Items.Add(p);
```

so here the pivot application has its content as page1

my problem is:
if create the button in page1 for navigate to another page called page2.

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
```

But when i try to navigate the app get crashed and i got the error log as follows
(this  error from listbox  seleciton changed)

```
 System.NullReferenceException at activity name(Object Sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) at 
     System.Windows.Controls.Prmitive.Selector/OnSelctionChanged
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got some code which is doing something when a selection changes that is being triggered when you navigate away from the first (pivot) page.

As it's coming from `System.Windows.Controls.Prmitive.Selector` I'm going to guess that you have some code for the pivot item selecction change that is the culprit. Possibly that as you navigate away there isn't a selection any more and you assume that there will always be one.

As a newbie, see also http://tinyurl.com/so-hints